# Issue with DateTime from DataTable C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a check on a DataTable. I need to know when a) there is an event called 'Start' in column 'Event', and b) that event was in the last 60 minutes, based on the values in column 'TimeActual'

Here's my code:

```
   DateTime last60minutes = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-60);
   var matchingRows = from row in trackingData.AsEnumerable()
   where row.Field<string>("Event") == "Start"
   && DateTime.Parse(row.Field<string>("TimeActual"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > last60minutes
   select row;

   Console.WriteLine(matchingRows.Count());
```

Here's the error:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.'

I'm presuming this is because the DateTime in the table is not a DateTime, but I'm already trying to convert it...any ideas?

I have also tried this code

```
        var matchingRows = from row in trackingData.AsEnumerable()
        where row.Field<string>("Event") == "Start"
        && row.Field<DateTime>("TimeActual") > last60minutes
        select row;

        Console.WriteLine(matchingRows.Count());
```

But I get this error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: Do you have a sample value from your dataset?

Comment: Why are you persisting a DateTime as a string? If its a datetime you should store it as such (as that type) and retrieve it as such. Then you do not have to convert anything, you do a direct comparison.

Comment: Try to convert it with format so DateTime.ParseExact(date, ''your format") https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Once you get this resolved keep in mind possible issues with time zones, if its a client/server architecture. In that case make sure all comparisons and persistence is done using UTC.

Comment: @Igor its just what comes in from an API as a JSON object and gets put into a DataTable. Are you saying I should be attempting to convert it before it goes into the table?

Comment: @reviloSlater - Yes. Convert to the appropriate type as early as possible. If you got json coming in you can automatically convert that string to a `DateTime` instance when you de-serialize the object. This can be done using existing libraries like `json.net`.

Comment: row.Field<string>("TimeActual") is already a DataTime and should be row.Field<DateTime>("TimeActual").

Comment: I'm assuming there is looping going on. Can you loop through and try to pinpoint if some records are successful and some aren't.  Maybe that only some records throw an error like maybe a null date?

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace? Also, if this is a database backed datatable, can you confirm that 'TimeActual' is actually a `string` type and not `DateTime` type?